# cypress type input text test fails on material-ui / formik (react app)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress, formik

I have testing login submit function with cypress.

Login form is built with material-ui and formik.

I can not get 'data-testid' props on Input when I run the test.

### testing code

```
describe('user', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:9080');
  });

  it('can visit login app', () => {
    cy.contains('login').click();
    cy.url().should('include', 'login');
    cy.get('[data-testid=username]').type('yuchung');
    cy.get('[data-testid=password]').type('yuchung1234');
    cy.get('button[type=submit]').click();

    cy.contains('logout');
  });
});
```

### error message

[image]

### sample code

[code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/yuchung-whglz?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [input docs](https://material-ui.com/api/input/),you have to pass the data test prop with the inputProps prop into the input field like this : `inputProps={{data-testid: 'username'}}`.

This will let you access the input field with the get function you are using and will actually type the text into the input.

Hope this helps.
 Happy coding.

Comment: `inputProps={{ 'data-testid': { name }, tabIndex: { name } }}` leads to an error `Not Found`.

Comment: You have to write it exactly like in my answer by wrapping name with "" and removing the {} around name .

Comment: `inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'username', tabIndex: 'username' }}`

Answer (score 0):

I would try with backticks I stead. See if it works that way..

```
cy.get(`[data-testid="username"]`).type('yuchung');
```

But If I am not mistaken formik supplies the Dom with unique names for the inputs. You can probably use them instead.  Use `cy.log` to print the values of the formik inputs.

Or you can also, I spect the DOM, manually see if the values are printed..

Comment: His access of the elements is correct as far as I can see.